# Parsing Hex dump

Tags: hex, hexdump, kaitai-struct

I recently came across a **kaitai struct** to deal with arbitrary binary formats. Now the thing is I have a **hex-dump** what I mean by that is I have a file which i want to parse and its in hex format when i use the **visualizer** in the **web ide** of **kaitai** for the mapping of data, it's converting the hex data again into hex is there any way i can convert the data from hex and get the exact hex data when i use the visualizer.

for example consider this 
3335363330 
and then again its  mapping it to 33 33 33 35 33 36 33 33 33 30

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Kaitai WebIDE & the console visualizer (`ksv`) does not support reading hex-encoded files, only raw binary files.

The solution is to convert the hex-encoded (text) file to a binary one first and then load the binary file into Kaitai.

You can do this by calling `xxd -r -p <input_file >output_file` on Linux or eg. calling this small Python script: `python -c "open('output_file','wb').write(open('input_file','r').read().strip().decode('hex'))"`. The latter works on any machine where Python 2 is installed.

Comment: converting the hex-encoded file to binary worked thanks a lot @koczkatamas you are a life saver